# Biopython Large Sequence splitting

Tags: python, biopython

I'm a newbie in the field of python programming. As I was trying to do some analysis,(I've tried to find the answer on other posts, but nothing) I decided to post my first and probably very foolish question. Why does this create only one output file although in this example there were supposed to be at least 8 (sequence is more than 8000 characters).
Thank you for your answer upfront.

```
def batch_iterator(iterator, batch_size) :
    entry = True
    while entry :
        batch = []
        while len(batch) < batch_size :
            try :
                entry = iterator.next()
            except StopIteration :
                entry = None
            if entry is None :
                #End of file
                break
            batch.append(entry)
        if batch :
            yield batch


from Bio import SeqIO
record_iter = SeqIO.parse(open("some.fasta"),"fasta")
for i, batch in enumerate(batch_iterator(record_iter, 1000)) :   #I think sth is wrong here?
    filename = "group_%i.fasta" % (i+1)
    handle = open(filename, "w")
    count = SeqIO.write(batch, handle, "fasta")
    handle.close()
    print "Wrote %i records to %s" % (count, filename)
```

Comment: What is the output of the `print "Wrote %i records to %s" % (count, filename)` statement?  Do you see it only printed once?

Comment: yes. THe output is whole thing printed only once :/

Comment: And the fact that the whole `batch_iterator` function is not correctly indented is just a bad copy here on Stack Overflow, otherwise it wouldn't even start working ... right?

Comment: but what is wrong, Please explain it to me if you think Im capable of understanding, otherwise just pass i guess..

Comment: Well, the whole `batch_iterator` function should be indented (usually, 4 spaces), instead of being aligned with the `def batch_iterator` line where it is declared.

Comment: Correct me If I misunderstood, but this doesn't work beacuse everything from "from Bio import SeqIO" on isnt indented 4 spaces?

Comment: No, it's exactly the opposite.  Look, I edited the code to make it right.  Now `batch_iterator` is correctly indented as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sequence chunks

After a long discussion with the OP, here is my very restructured proposal, using the generator function defined in [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

```
# file: main.py
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord


def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handle = open('long.fasta', 'r')
    records = list(SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"))
    record = records[0]

    for pos, chunk in enumerate(chunks(record.seq.tostring(), 1000)):
        chunk_record = SeqRecord(Seq(
            chunk, record.seq.alphabet),
            id=record.id, name=record.name,
            description=record.description)
        outfile = "group_%d.fasta" % pos
        SeqIO.write(chunk_record, open(outfile, 'w'), "fasta")
```

Note that your original code does something very different: it takes **new records** from the generator provided by the `SeqIO.parse` function, and tries to store them in different files.  If you want to split **a single record** in smaller sub-sequences, you have to access the record's internal data, which is done by `record.seq.tostring()`.  The `chunks` generator function, as described in the other thread linked above, returns as many chunks as is possible to build from the passed in sequence.  Each of them is stored as a new fasta record in a different file (if you want to keep just the sequence, write the `chunk` directly to the opened `outfile`).

#### Check that it works

Consider the following code:

```
# file: generate.py
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio import SeqIO

long_string = "A" * 8000
outfile = open('long.fasta', 'w')

record = SeqRecord(Seq(
    long_string,
    IUPAC.protein),
    id="YP_025292.1", name="HokC",
    description="toxic membrane protein, small")

SeqIO.write(record, outfile, "fasta")
```

It writes a single record to a file named "long.fasta". This single record has a Sequence inside that is 8000 characters long, as generated in `long_string`.

How to use it:

```
$ python generate.py
$ wc -c long.fasta
8177 long.fasta
```

The overhead over 8000 characters is the file header.

How to split that file in chunks of 1000 length each, with the code snippet above:

```
$ python main.py
$ ls
generate.py   group_1.fasta group_3.fasta group_5.fasta group_7.fasta main.py
group_0.fasta group_2.fasta group_4.fasta group_6.fasta long.fasta
$ wc -c group_*
1060 group_0.fasta
1060 group_1.fasta
1060 group_2.fasta
1060 group_3.fasta
1060 group_4.fasta
1060 group_5.fasta
1060 group_6.fasta
1060 group_7.fasta
8480 total
```

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work, the reason why I tried to do things with iteration is for effective memory use, I'm sure there is some very simple solution to that

Comment: But `SeqIO.parse` is [already returning you a SeqRecord iterator](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO#Sequence_Input). The fact that you grow the `batch` list on a separate iterator function or inside the main loop is not going to affect memory usage, AFAICT.

Comment: the code should create many files with 1000 units long sequences, instead it jsut duplicattes the whole thing.

Comment: Wrote 1 records to group_1.fasta is the output it gives me although the fasta is way larger than just 1000 characters

Comment: I just checked that it works.  Is it possible that I misunderstood your expected output?  Do you want to split the records, or the content of a single record?  The code you have shown, as far as I can tell, is doing the former.

Comment: I am so so sorry. I tried to split the contents of a single file. For example: I've had a 90000 chars long fasta and I tried to split it into equally sized chunks. http://biopython.org/wiki/Split_large_file , this is what I tried but It still doesn't work :/ as you see I've tried to build the code  from smaller blocks, but it still doesnt split my fasta into smaller ones.

Comment: @user3523464: I have rearranged completely my answer because now I understand better what you are trying to accomplish.  Don't apologize, I am sorry for my part that I did not understand well your question, possibly misleading you! :)

Comment: No problem.  Could you please accept the answer, if it is indeed what you were looking for? Thanks!